# Bigcommerce stencil bundle without minifying javascript

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I'm having a javascript error in production that I can not duplicate in development. This is the offending module:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.core';
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery';
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.keyboard';
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.box';
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.motion';
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.triggers';
import 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.dropdown';

export default function() {
  $(window).on('changed.zf.mediaquery', function(event, newSize, oldSize){
    toggle();
  });

  // toggle on page load
  toggle();
}

function toggle() {
  const $drop = $('[data-more-categories-dropdown]');

  if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast('medium')) {
    if ($drop.data('dropdown')) {
      $drop.foundation('destroy');
      $drop.removeData('dropdown');
      $drop.attr('style', '');
    }
  }
  else {
    if (!$drop.data('dropdown')) {
      new Foundation.Dropdown($drop, {
        closeOnClick: true
      });
    }
  }
}
```

The purpose of the module is simply to destroy a foundation dropdown menu when the screen breakpoint changes. If the new breakpoint is medium or larger, and the dropdown exists, destroy it. If the breakpoint is smaller than medium and the dropdown does not exist, create it.

This works exactly as desired in my local development version of the store. Then, I run 'stencil bundle', and upload the theme to a live store. When I do that, I get an error every time I resize the browser to a breakpoint of medium or larger. The error is:

```
bundle.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: We're sorry, 'destroy' is not an available method for this element.
```

This is very difficult to troubleshoot since all of the javascript is minified into the `bundle.js` file, and I can't reproduce the issue in development.

Is there any way (even a hacky way) to tell the `stencil bundle` to treat the javascript like it does in development? That way I can leave `debugger` statements in the code and have source maps to help me figure out why the behavior is different in production.

If anyone has any other ideas as to what might cause this, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you are minifying the foundation library, and that is messing up variable/function names.  Maybe try including a minified version of that separately.

Comment: Thanks @user3413723. You're right I am minifying the foundation library, I think. It's included in the webpack config because the foundation libraries need to be translated from ES6. You think that's causing the problem? Can you explain further? I'm still a little lost.

Comment: Well I know minifying sometimes changes out the names of functions and variables so they are shorter.  Maybe in the process of minifying foundation the minifier changed the `destroy` function's name to something shorter.  So maybe browse the foundation website and find  a minified version there, download it, and include it in your page, then remove your version.  They will surely have tested their minified version to make sure it works.  If it works - you have found your problem.  If not - you know it's not minification to blame.

Comment: Ah I see your answer now -must have been that the element wasn't created yet.  Good work!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why, but I made a small change to the module and it seems to have fixed the problem. I'm now using the `zfPlugin` data attribute to check if the dropdown is initiated or not. Here's the new `toggle` function.

```
function toggle() {
  const $drop = $('[data-more-categories-dropdown]');

  if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast('medium')) {
    if ($drop.data('zfPlugin')) {
      $drop.foundation('destroy');
      $drop.attr('style', '');
    }
  }
  else {
    if (!$drop.data('zfPlugin')) {
      new Foundation.Dropdown($drop, {
        closeOnClick: true
      });
    }
  }
}
```